# This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to print text with 6 textboxes to word
But the program stops and gives me this message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0fFJ.png)
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND)).'

What is the solution to this message please

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
' Create Word Application
Dim oWord As Word.Application = CreateObject("Word.Application")

```
    ' Open existing word document     
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document = oWord.Documents.Open("D:\myfile.doc")
    Dim oTable As Word.Table
    oWord.Visible = True

    'Insert a table with 1 row x 5 columns and fill it with five TextBox.Text     
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
    oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, 3, 6)

    oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6

    oTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = TxtBook.Text
    oTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = TxtAuthor.Text
    oTable.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = TxtPublisher.Text
    oTable.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = TxtPublish.Text
    oTable.Cell(1, 5).Range.Text = txtPage.Text
    oTable.Cell(1, 6).Range.Text = TxtNote.Text
    ' Save this word document     
    oDoc.SaveAs("D:\myfile.doc", True)
    oDoc.Close()
    oWord.Application.Quit()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

oWord.Documents is a collection of documents, not a document itself.
try

```
Dim oDoc As Word.Document = oWord.Documents.Add("D:\myfile.doc")
```

**EDIT:**

Although this first answer is necessary, it is not sufficient because you have a problem of incorrect COM Interop settings in the Windows registry :

to check COM installation have a look to this registry key (64bit Office:) :

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\Interface\[00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046]\TypeLib
```

(on my computer I see this)

```
default Value = {00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
Version Value = 8.5
```

then browse to the registry key

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\TypeLib\{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`
```

you must find a subkey with same name than last version value ("8.5" in my case) with this content :

```
default Value              = "Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library"
PrimaryInteropAssemblyName = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"
```

I made a screen image to help you :[image]

if you don't find this keys or find multiple keys 8.5, 8.6 etc..., you must repair office installation or reinstall it.

Comment: sorry it's give me the same  error